# Plotting a function with matplotlib

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib, plot

So I have defined a function, and for some reason the terminal is returning the following error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I'm not sure what I have done wrong exactly?

Here is my self-contained function with corresponding plot:

```
import matplotlib
import math
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

def rotation_curve(r):
    v_rotation = math.sqrt((r*(1.33*(10**32)))/(1+r)**2)
    return v_rotation

curve_range = numpy.linspace(0, 100, 10000)

fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(16,6))

gridspec_layout = gridspec.GridSpec(1,1)
pyplot = fig.add_subplot(gridspec_layout[0])

pyplot.plot(curve_range, rotation_curve(curve_range))

matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

Could anyone advise me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: please add the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of `rotation_curve(r)`.  You input and manipulate a numpy array (`curve_range`), but you do so using a non-vectorized function `math.sqrt`:

```
v_rotation = math.sqrt((r*(1.33*(10**32)))/(1+r)**2)
```

Instead, use `numpy.sqrt` which broadcasts the sqrt operation across every element in the array.  The multiplication and exponentiation operators are overloaded in numpy arrays, so those should work fine.

```
def rotation_curve(r):
    v_rotation = numpy.sqrt((r*(1.33*(10**32)))/(1+r)**2)
    return v_rotation
```

Comment: Closer. It is now giving me the following ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension. Traces back to pyplot.plot(rotation_curve, rotation_curve(curve_range))

Comment: Fixed the problem, ignore previous comment.